# Security code review Apple Swift - tools and documentation

Tags: mobile, ios, code-review, static-analysis

I need to perform a security code review on a huge Swift application. I have done many mobile penetration tests before and some code review but never on iOS Swift Apps. I am primarily looking for information and reference material which will help me answer the two questions:

1. Could you provide information on how to conduct a source code reviews of Swift and Swift code for security flaws.
2. What would be a good approach for automating the source code review using either static or dymanic analysis of the source code?

Comment: The problem is that such questions (both: asking for product recommendations and for references to outside materials) are off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

I encourage you try out https://www.kiuwan.com
It has out of the box custom rules for Swift, it allows for custom rule creation and has scored the highest benchmark on Owasp for SAST vendors.
Disclaimer: I work there

Answer (score -1):

A quick google search brought me to [Tailor](https://tailor.sh/) I have never used it though.
Also [Hp Fortify](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/software-solutions/application-security/) and [Checkmarx](https://www.checkmarx.com/) can help scan your code but do involve huge upfront cost.